# Best way to write lingq for loop queries

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am using oracleDB and i have view like below which contains employees and his managers.

```
empNo
FirstName
LastName
Manager
```

I need to select a person and all of his staff. IE

```
Person1 is Manager 
-- Person1_1
----Person1_1_1
----Person1_1_2
-- Person1_1
```

When i login with the user of `Person1`, I need to get all of the persons above.

Here is my LINQ but it is too slow.. What is the efficient way to get the data ?

```
List<decimal> OrgPerson2 = new List<decimal>();
public List<decimal> getOrgPerson(decimal empNo)
{
    List<decimal> OrgPerson = new List<decimal>();
    OrgPerson.AddRange(db.CRM_PERSON_TITLE_V.Where(c => c.MANAGER == empNo).Select(c => (decimal)c.PERSONID).ToList());
    var subPerson = db.CRM_PERSON_TITLE_V.ToList();

    foreach (var item in OrgPerson)
    {
        OrgPerson2.Add(item);
        var subPerson2 = subPerson.Where(c => c.MANAGER == item).Select(c => (decimal)c.PERSONID).ToList();
        if (subPerson2 != null)
        {
            if (subPerson2.Count > 0)
            {
                getOrgPerson(item);
            }
        }
    }
    return OrgPerson2.Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Comment: Get rid of all ToList() calls you can, they usually really slow things down. Call ToList after the collection is built.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to try out your solution and as I suspected it threw a StackOverflowException for me. Recursive methods are pretty bad if you are not careful.

Here's my solution with a stack. The code is self-explanatory.

```
    List<decimal> GetOrgPerson(decimal id)
    {
        Stack<Person> iter = new Stack<Person>();
        List<decimal> result = new List<decimal>();

        iter.Push(db.People.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ID == id));

        while (iter.Count() > 0)
        {
            Person current = iter.Pop();

            var subordinates = db.People.Where(p => p.ManagerID == current.ID);

            foreach (var s in subordinates)
            {
                if (result.Contains(s.ID))
                    continue;

                iter.Push(s);
                result.Add(s.ID);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

In my test-case People inherits IEnumerable interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is just getting all the staff under a manager recursively, it can be greatly simplified:

```
public IEmunerable<decimal> getOrgPerson(decimal empNo)
{
    foreach (var subEmpNo in db.CRM_PERSON_TITLE_V.Where(c => c.MANAGER == empNo).Select(c => (decimal)c.PERSONID))
    {
        yield return subEmpNo;
        foreach (var subSubEmpNo in getOrgPerson(subEmpNo))
            yield return subSubEmpNo;
    }
}
```

You should not need `Distinct()` since each employee has only one manager.

Also, I assume you don't need a `List<decimal>` which you can add/remove items. Otherwise, you may need something like `OrgPerson2 = getOrgPerson(empNo).ToList()`